# Unit Testing for Windows Phone 7 - App does not launch correctly

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I am developing a Wp7-App and I want to start Unit Testing. I used the Template from Visual Studio 2010 to create a Windows Phone 7.1 UnitTest-Project and I added the required Assemblies via Nu-Manager.

I can't start the project in emulator or on a real device. I get a blank loading-screen and this error message: 
A first chance exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Is this a known error? Is there a workaround?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The standard VS Unit test template won't work for WP7.  You should look at these links:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX10/CL59
and
http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/06/updated-ut-mango-bits/

I have a Silverlight 4 Test Project using the Jeff Wilcox assemblies and it works fine for my WP7 tests.  I use [TestClass] and [TestMethod] attributes and these namespaces inside my tests:

```
using Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing; using
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
```

Within the App.xaml.cs file there is minimal code and the following starts it all off:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    RootVisual = UnitTestSystem.CreateTestPage();
}
```